# Java Spring MVC display PDF in browser

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf

How do I force the browser to display the pdf instead of downloading ? 
Here is the controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/preview.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected String preivewSection(      
    HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession httpSession,
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        byte[] documentInBytes = getDocument();         
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(documentInBytes.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(documentInBytes);
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
    } finally {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the above mentioned controller is all we need from the server side, the problem is the browser doesn't support viewing PDF files.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove this line, the pdf will open in the browser itself.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this google chrome browser not support preview It.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
```

But I changed this header as :

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.getName());
```

preview ok !

Because `inline (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 0):

after checking the response from the postman, if result like this will work on chrome

> **Content-Disposition: name="inline"; filename="XXX.pdf"**

i think the questioner param less the "name="

> Content-Disposition: inline; filename="XXX.pdf" (not working on chrome)

if not set Content-Disposition some framework will auto add a default become

> Content-Disposition: name="attachment"; filename="f.txt" (not working on chrome)

some plugin auto add "form-data; "before the header become:

> Content-Disposition: form-data;name="inline"; filename="XXX.pdf" (not working on chrome)