# How to display uploaded doc (ms word) & PDF in browser Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, pdf

I designed a spring MVC application where User can upload doc or pdf files to application and it will be stored in My SQL.

I made download link so that user can download the uploaded file and it works fine.

How could we make it readable online (without downloading) in User's browser(like [www.scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com))? (As of now I made tag `<embed src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ebook/${ebook.filename}" width="1000" height="2000" />` tag in HTML, PDF views perfect as PDF reader is installed in PCand PDF plugin is installed in browser but doc file not displayed)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551106/java-spring-mvc-display-pdf-in-browser) he says browsers doesn't support viewing PDF files.(even .doc files)

Is there any plugins do render uploaded doc/pdf files in the browser to be read online?

Answer (score 0):

check out http://viewerjs.org
I've only tried it minimally for PDF (it seems to work), but they advertise the capability to render Office documents as well.

Comment: Thank you @GreyBeardedGeek . I tried it. How to use this with Spring MVC appliaction? I get `HTTP Status 404 - /ViewerJS/` when I follow the instructions. here (http://viewerjs.org/instructions/)